# Pandas sawp columns with multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

[image: Initial Data]

This is how my data looks like when I read it from a csv file, I am reading using multi-level index (Body Type and Spending).

What I want is to have an "Year" column and all the values in Spending should appear as individual columns. Basically I want to swap/transpose "Spending" with "Years"

The end data should look like this

[image: Expectation]

I found a way to do this, but it doesn't seem efficient. I was wondering if there is a better and cleaner way to do this? I see few examples of pd.swapaxes(), but couldn't get it to work.

Here is the code I used:

```
d = [
    ["Small Narrowbodies", "TotalExpenses", "2326550.00", "2566989.00", "2710156.00"],
    ["Small Narrowbodies", "Pilots (000)", "583404.00", "627762.00", "669258.00"],
    [
        "Small Narrowbodies",
        "Salaries and Wages (000)",
        "432613.00",
        "469059.00",
        "515538.00",
    ],
    ["Small Narrowbodies", "Pilot Training (000)", "28235.00", "22388.00", "23838.00"],
    [
        "Small Narrowbodies",
        "Benefits and Payroll Taxes (000)",
        "77752.00",
        "87128.00",
        "77679.00",
    ],
    [
        "Small Narrowbodies",
        "Per Diem/ Personnel (000)",
        "44804.00",
        "49187.00",
        "52203.00",
    ],
    [
        "Small Narrowbodies",
        "Purchased Goods (000)",
        "627471.00",
        "792582.00",
        "772448.00",
    ],
    ["Small Narrowbodies", "Fuel/Oil (000)", "559698.00", "684007.00", "670673.00"],
    ["Small Narrowbodies", "Insurance (000)", "7483.00", "5449.00", "4200.00"],
    [
        "Small Narrowbodies",
        "Other (inc. Tax) (000)",
        "60290.00",
        "103126.00",
        "97575.00",
    ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=["Body_Type", "Spending", "1995", "1996", "1997"])

df2 = df.set_index(["Body_Type", "Spending"])

df3 = df2.transpose().unstack(level=-1).reset_index()

df3.columns = ["Body_Type", "Spending", "Year", "Amount"]

df4 = df3.pivot_table(
    index["Body_Type", "Year"], columns="Spending", values="Amount", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: please don't post images @tapaskumarMahanta...

Comment: nothing absurd about transpose, it's transposing your index which is two levels. can you provide some sample data [mcve]

Comment: @Datanovice can I upload files here?

Comment: You can either re create your dataframe as code or share a textual sample of it.

Comment: @Datanovice I have updated the post with reproducible codes

Comment: just change your last call ? `
`df4 = df3.pivot_table(
    index["Body_Type", "Spending"], columns="Year", values="Amount", aggfunc=np.sum
)`

Comment: @Datanovice What I need is an easier/ cleaner way to get to df4 from df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like

```
df=df.unstack(level=0).stack(level=0)
```

Comment: it throws this error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: @tapaskumarMahanta how about df.stack().unstack(level=1)

Comment: No didn't work either. I was hoping df.unstack(level=-1).stack(level=1) would work. It didn't. I think when we remove "Spending", Body Type becomes common for many rows, so it is not unique, so can not work as an index? if somehow we can swap without unstacking that might work.